# Weird behavior of DecimalFormatted String

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying to make a calculator that automatically have 2 decimal places in it then pressing a numbered `Button` adds it to the value displayed in a `TextView` while maintaining the 2 decimal places. For example, if a pressed 1, the value should be 0.01. But it seems like I found a weird behavior of `String`, I'm not sure which part of what I'm currently doing.

This is my relevant code

```
public void keyPressed(View v){
    String btnTxtVal = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
    String lblTxtVal = lblInput.getText().toString();

    inputTxt.append(btnTxtVal);
    temp = Double.parseDouble(inputTxt.toString()) / 100;

    lblInput.setText(decimalFormat.format(temp));
    Log.d(TAG, "btn: "+btnTxtVal+" temp: "+temp);
    Log.d(TAG, "formattedTemp: "+decimalFormat.format(temp));
}
```

The code above is called via a DataBinding because it's inside a `Fragment`.

The problem is that when I pressed a numbered `Button` after pressing the zero `Button`, for some reason, an extra zero is added in-front of the number.

This is what my log looks like.

```
pressedBtn: 1 temp: 0.01
formattedTemp: 0.01

pressedBtn: 2 temp: 0.12
formattedTemp: 0.12

pressedBtn: 3 temp: 1.23
formattedTemp: 1.23

pressedBtn: 4 temp: 12.34
formattedTemp: 12.34

pressedBtn: 00 temp: 1234.0
formattedTemp: 1,234

pressedBtn: 0 temp: 12340.0
formattedTemp: 12,340

pressedBtn: 3 temp: 123400.03
formattedTemp: 123,400.03
```

This the code I'm currently using.

```
public class KeypadFragment extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;
    private Button btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9, btn0, btn00, btnDelete, btnPlus;
    private TextView lblInput;
    private Double firstInput = 0.00, secondInput = 0.00, temp = 0.00, currentSum = 0.00;
    private DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,###.##");
    private StringBuilder inputTxt = new StringBuilder();
    String TAG = "sharePOS";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_keypad, container, false);

        btn1 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad1);
        btn2 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad2);
        btn3 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad3);
        btn4 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad4);
        btn5 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad5);
        btn6 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad6);
        btn7 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad7);
        btn8 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad8);
        btn9 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad9);
        btn0 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad0);
        btn00 = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypad00);
        btnDelete = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypadDelete);
        btnPlus = rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnKeypadAdd);
        lblInput = rootView.findViewById(R.id.lblKeypadInput);

        FragmentKeypadBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(rootView);
        binding.setFragment(this);

        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lblInput.setText("0.00");

                inputTxt = new StringBuilder();

                if(firstInput == 0.00){
                    firstInput = Double.parseDouble(lblInput.getText().toString());
                }else if(secondInput == 0.00){
                    secondInput = Double.parseDouble(lblInput.getText().toString());

                    firstInput += secondInput;
                    secondInput = 0.00;
                }

            }
        });

        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lblInput.setText("0.00");

                inputTxt = new StringBuilder();
                firstInput = 0.00;
                secondInput = 0.00;
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    public void keyPressed(View v){
        String btnTxtVal = ((Button) v).getText().toString();
        String lblTxtVal = lblInput.getText().toString();

        inputTxt.append(btnTxtVal);
        temp = Double.parseDouble(inputTxt.toString()) / 100;

        lblInput.setText(decimalFormat.format(temp));
        Log.d(TAG, "btn: "+btnTxtVal+" temp: "+temp);
        Log.d(TAG, "formattedTemp: "+decimalFormat.format(temp));
    }

}
```

My layout has a separate `0` and `00` `Button`.

Comment: What is your "decimalFormat"

Comment: I guess you mean `pressedBtn: 00`, right? Is that really the same button as you used in `pressedBtn: 0`? That doesn't look like an issue in String, but rather an unexpected value coming from `((Button) v).getText().toString()`.

Comment: I don't see any weird behavior. Your output is exactly what I would expect looking at your code.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Look again at the last three logs.. It goes from `12340.0` to `123,400.03` after pressing `3` after the `0`. Btw, _minaj_, is `pressedBtn: 00` a typo or you literally copy-pasted your log. And what is your `decimalFormat`?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Fair point. The last input/output combo is indeed weird.

Comment: What output did you expect?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen it's a copy-paste of the log. You could look at my updated post for everything in my code.

Comment: @Sweeper what I expected is that after pressed a non-zero `Button` after a zero, it would just add the number at the end of the `String` without a leading zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code you've displayed seems to work as intended. Here a mini sample project based on your code as prove it is working as it should:

```
class Main{
  public static void main(String[] a){
    String lblTextVal = "0.00";
    String inputText = "";
    System.out.println("Starting with: lblTextVal: "+lblTextVal + " inputText: \""+inputText+"\"");
    System.out.println();

    java.text.NumberFormat decimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("#,##0.00");

    for(String btnPress : new String[]{"1","2","3","4","0","0","3"}){
      inputText += btnPress;                    // inputTxt.append(btnTxtVal);
      Double temp = Double.parseDouble(inputText.toString()) / 100;
      lblTextVal = decimalFormat.format(temp);  // lblInput.setText(decimalFormat.format(temp));

      System.out.println("pressedBtn: "+btnPress+" temp: "+temp);
      System.out.println("formattedTemp: "+decimalFormat.format(temp));
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

[**Try it online.**](https://tio.run/##jVLBTsMwDL3vK6zs0qoj6xinTrugCYkDCGkTF@CQrhl0tGnUuhto2rcXp01LJ22ISm7i@PnZfslW7MTVNvqsqnUiigIeRKwOAwBdhkm8hgIF0rLL4ghSCjlLzGP1/vIGwjUwgOYAkjBZyS98FgnMgfnc99msH4@VLtEgTLgNfRcoU56VyDWBMFEOW6LI0STsY/wIerQBMK9XxAP2yxnAK2Ne53qMXPdiDRupf1sanyPl8McyDWV@l@WpQIjkOk5FYr05KLnvQRf9qMOGo@GwHpiIa9JNlludIET1lEvSNag5WvUObMJG7JpsSnZD5lubsqMVFnqaefOOaQZnvvHYgqk7obVUkUP4VS2VHRdgkdGdSiA5NI3UeFyLvJDN3unqccyaTh3XhTFMfL/lOLnmE5X4ppHD0LuzuiUC3xtKXsia1rmc0DVpl3NPQ5vxZXSLyryFVg@P1ROZo6b0HwxNRZTRymb8o6HLD@g4MHasqh8)

The weird part in your log are the last three parts:

```
pressedBtn: 00 temp: 1234.0
formattedTemp: 1,234

pressedBtn: 0 temp: 12340.0
formattedTemp: 12,340

pressedBtn: 3 temp: 123400.03
formattedTemp: 123,400.03
```

Which should have been this instead:

```
pressedBtn: 0 temp: 123.4
formattedTemp: 123.40

pressedBtn: 0 temp: 1234.0
formattedTemp: 1,234.00

pressedBtn: 3 temp: 12340.03
formattedTemp: 12,340.03
```

Based on your code I only see one of three possible reasons:

1. Your `decimalFormat` is incorrect.
2. You have a button `00` for some reason, which appends two `00`s at once instead of a single `0`.
3. You append to `inputTxt` somewhere else in between.

The most likely cause is probably option 2, which your log seems to reflect. Although option 1 is also definitely incorrect, since your `formattedTemp` lacks decimal values at the second to last and third to last parts (top two in the three I copied above).

Comment: I do have a `Button` for `00`. But even using the single `0` `Button`, the weird still happens. I just copied my `DecimalFormat` somewhere so maybe that's also incorrect.

Comment: Man, I think it was really the `DecimalFormat`. I'm now using `#,##0.00` as my format.